is it problematic to disable 'session optional pam_systemd.so' in etc/pam.d/common-session/ to execute one line to speed up boot time?
At boot im running following command:
su vis -c 'QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen /usr/bin/browser --version'
/usr/bin/browser being a custom browser, which cannot be run as root. The script that is executing this command however is run as root, meaning to prevent /usr/bin/browser from being run as root I have to use su to switch to another user. This is a debian embedded system and because of the su this command is taking a long time(2+ min). I have seen that as a workaround you can disable  session optional pam_systemd.so inside /etc/pam.d/common-session.
Workaround mentioned here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1050717/why-su-command-takes-to-long-in-nested-debian-lxd-containers
So i figured i can just disable it execute the command and then enable it again, like so:
sudo sed -i '/^session\s\+optional\s\+pam_systemd\.so/s/^/# /' /etc/pam.d/common-session

su vis -c 'QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen /usr/bin/browser --version'

sudo sed -i '/^#\s\+session\s\+optional\s\+pam_systemd\.so/s/^#\s\+//' /etc/pam.d/common-session

the first sed adds a # to session optional pam_systemd.so and the second sed removes it again.
This does indeed work, no more 2+ min waiting on each boot, but im just wondering if this causes any potential issues that im unaware of. The system is debian bullseye on armhf.
